# Java: Which are the implicit encodings used for Sytem.out/in/err, files?

Tags: java, encoding, charset

First task: I want to read from System.in into a reader.
It seems that this is done via

```
InputStreamReader cin = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
```

Well there are other constructors including an encoding.
It is not clear what there the default encoding is.
As I understand, System.in is just a stream of bytes.
Whereas InputStreamReader reads chars.
But where does constructor of InputStream know the charset?
Do i have to apply a specific charset? if so which one or do i have to leave it away?

According question concerning System.out and System.err.
Both seem to be print streams and in particular reading bytes.

```
OutputStreamWriter out  = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
```

ok choosing the right encoding or do i have to use a different constructor?

What about System.err?

Also what are the charsets????

Same question i have for PipedReader/Writer.
At least they must coincide, right?

For StringWriter/Reader: same encoding as string, i.e. utf8, right?

Last question concerning files.
FileReader/Writer are subclasses of InputStreamReader/Writer.
This seems reasonable, since files are a sequence of bytes.
But unlike constructor of InputStreamReader/Writer,
which have constructors with charsets, FileReader/Writer do not.
how can they know the encoding of the file???

Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to read from System.in into a reader ...via
> `InputStreamReader cin = new InputStreamReader(System.in);`
> It is not clear what there the default encoding is. As I understand, System.in is just a stream of bytes. Whereas InputStreamReader reads chars. But where does constructor of InputStream know the charset?

A person who might hypothetically want to know about an element of the Java standard library could conceivably **look at the documentation** namely [the Javadoc for that ctor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.InputStream)) which says

> Creates an InputStreamReader that uses the default charset.

In older versions that was actually a hyperlink, but no longer. However the text at the top of the page describing the class as a whole says

> An InputStreamReader is a bridge from byte streams to character streams: It reads bytes and decodes them into characters using a specified charset. The charset that it uses may be specified by name or may be given explicitly, or the platform's default charset may be accepted.

and *that* charset does hyperlink to [the class `java.nio.charset.Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) which says

> Every instance of the Java virtual machine has a default charset, which may or may not be one of the standard charsets. The default charset is determined during virtual-machine startup and typically depends upon the locale and charset being used by the underlying operating system.

and documents a [method you can call](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset()) to find out that default.

> Do i have to apply a specific charset? if so which one or do i have to leave it away?

Depends on the data you will be reading. If Java is run with its standard input from a 'terminal' (in Unix) or 'console' (in Windows), *typically* input by the user will match the locale (or Windows codepage) set in the OS, which as above is used for the Java default, so you can use the default. If the input will be redirected from a file (or on Unix a 'heredoc', which is effectively a temporary file) it depends on what's in the file; if input will be redirected from a pipe from another program (on some Unix shells including a process substitution) it depends on what that other program outputs -- if it is running in the same system it is *likely* (but not certain) to be using the same locale as is set for the Java process.

> According question concerning System.out and System.err. Both seem to be print streams and in particular reading bytes.

(Aside: 'according' is not grammatical there. You could say '[the/a] corresponding question', but just '[the] same question' is correct and much clearer.)

Yes, `System.out .err` are instances of `PrintStream` (or a subclass) [Javadoc here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html), which is a special case and kind of a hybrid; it handles writing (not reading) bytes the same as any other `OutputStream` but also has the same `print*` and `printf/format` methods as `PrintWriter`. An actual `PrintWriter` would format (if necessary) the output as characters and (usually) pass them to an `OutputStreamWriter` which encodes the characters as bytes and passes to the underlying stream, but `PrintStream` does both the formatting and encoding itself, directly outputting bytes. Looking at the list of ctors, you can see that you can either specify a charset name or object, or use the default; the implementations of `System.out .err` use the default.

If you do create your own `OutputStreamWriter` on (the stream part of) these `PrintStream`s, you can either specify any charset or use the default -- although if you're going to use the default why not just use the `PrintStream` directly?

> Also what are the charsets????

If you mean the concept, see the class documentation I linked above. If you mean what specific charsets are available on a given JVM, that can vary. You can get the current list at a point in time using the static method `availableCharsets()` in that class.

> Same question i have for PipedReader/Writer. At least they must coincide, right?
> For StringWriter/Reader: same encoding as string, i.e. utf8, right?

These are different. They do not work in bytes, at least not visibly.

Taking `String` first, Java `String` is defined to consist of 16-bit `char`s, not bytes. Originally, when Unicode was also 16 bits, these were truly characters (what are now called UCS-2). When Unicode grew beyond 16 bits but Java couldn't easily change to follow, these became UTF-16 code elements, which are *mostly* characters but one group, called surrogates, are used in *pairs* to represent 'supplemental' characters. Recent versions of Java (9 up, IIRC) actually *store* `String` data as single bytes if and only if all the UTF-16 code elements fit in one byte, which is equivalent to them being in the ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) charset. But this is purely internal; the API still accepts and returns `char char[]` etc. Thus no encoding and decoding of the type envisioned by the NIO/Charset model is done, and no charset(s) is(are) involved.

Although byte-oriented `Piped{Input,Output}Stream` also exist, `Piped{Reader,Writer}` don't use them; they instead simply store the `char` sequences provided on the write side and return them on the read side. Again no encoding or decoding is done and no charset(s) is(are) involved.

> Last question concerning files. FileReader/Writer are subclasses of InputStreamReader/Writer. This seems reasonable, since files are a sequence of bytes. But unlike constructor of InputStreamReader/Writer, which have constructors with charsets, FileReader/Writer do not. how can they know the encoding of the file???

(edit) That's no longer true as of Java 11; now they *do* have ctors with charsets, and the ones that don't specify a charset are documented to use the default charset; see [FileReader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileReader.html#constructor.summary) and [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileWriter.html#constructor.summary). To be clear, a Reader doesn't know the actual encoding of the file contents (assuming there are some), it only knows what you said to use or the default; if that doesn't match the actual file contents, you're likely to get partially or totally garbaged data. A Writer does write the encoding you specified or defaulted, so the contents (or at least the *new* contents when appending) will be in that encoding.
Before 11, the [class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) [summaries](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) say "The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding and the default byte-buffer size are appropriate."

Comment: I did read the api docs. And I even found the method Charset.defaultCharset() but was not sure whether this is the one meant at the docs of InputStreamReader. I even read the sources but leads to private classes quite quickly.

Comment: Ah concerning FileReader/Writer, the constructors with Charset seems to be added somewhere in between java 8 and java 11.

Comment: You're right: they were added in 11, which is indicated in each individual ctor doc entry but not the summary. Fixed.